# Why does Java GUI component shift when another is not visible?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

Here is the issue I am having. I have a `JToolBar` that contains 3 `JPanel`'s and each panel contains some various components. The panel that contains my `JProgressBar` is only visible when there is something loading. What happens when it changes from visible to not visible is my other two panels shift by approx 1 pixel. Here is the code:

```
private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL);
private JPanel progressPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel globalPanel = new JPanel();
private JPanel cameraPanel = new JPanel();
private JLabel cameraLabel = new JLabel("Camera: ");
private JLabel cameraCoords = new JLabel();
private JLabel globalLabel = new JLabel("Global: ");
private JLabel globalCoords = new JLabel();

progressPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(progressPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
progressPanel.setBackground(Color.RED);
globalPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(globalPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
globalPanel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
cameraPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cameraPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
cameraPanel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

progressBar.setFocusable(false);
progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,0));
progressBar.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150,20));
progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
//progressBar.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

progressPanel.add(progressBar);
//globalLabel.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
//globalCoords.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
globalPanel.add(globalLabel);
globalPanel.add(globalCoords);

//cameraLabel.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
//cameraCoords.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
cameraPanel.add(cameraLabel);
cameraPanel.add(cameraCoords);


this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,30));
this.add(progressPanel);
this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
this.addSeparator();
this.add(globalPanel);
this.addSeparator();
this.add(cameraPanel);
this.setFloatable(false);
```

Now when ever I set `progressPanel.setVisible(false)` the `JLabel`'s shift by a pixel. Where I have the alignment commented out is where I tried to get them to align, but this still did not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Horizontally or vertically? An applet would be useful, if you have somewhere to host it.

Comment: The ToolBar is horizontal, but the labels shift vertically. When the componenet is visible the labels are shifted up, and then back to "normal" when it is not visible. I colored the backgrounds of the panels that the labels are contained in and confirmed that it actually is the labels moving and not the whole panel itself. I do not have anywhere to host it.

Comment: I fixed my problem, it was caused by the BoxLayout that I was using for the JToolBar, I also switched out the JToolBar for a JPanel. I still do not know what caused this behavior, but switching to the Border Layout fixed my issue.

Comment: Why not add your findings and corrected code as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class StatusBar extends JPanel{ //Instead of JToolBar
    private JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(JProgressBar.HORIZONTAL);
    private JPanel progressPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel globalPanel = new JPanel();
    private JPanel cameraPanel = new JPanel();
    private JLabel cameraLabel = new JLabel("Camera: ");
    private JLabel cameraCoords = new JLabel();
    private JLabel globalLabel = new JLabel("Global: ");
    private JLabel globalCoords = new JLabel();

    public StatusBar(){
        progressPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(progressPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        globalPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(globalPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        cameraPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(cameraPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

        progressBar.setFocusable(false);
        progressBar.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,0));
        progressBar.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(150,20));
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);

        progressPanel.add(tileLoadingLabel);
        progressPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(5));
        progressPanel.add(progressBar);
        globalPanel.add(globalLabel);
        globalPanel.add(globalCoords);
        globalPanel.add(separator);
        globalCoords.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,0));

        //Here is where I made the change(after extending JPanel and not JToolBar
        //I used the BorderLayout instead of the BoxLayout  
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(0,30));
        this.add(globalPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        this.add(progressPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
    }
}
```

I did not think about posting the answer myself, I will know for the future, thanks for the insight :)